# Widget with arbitrary width that is swipeable

Tags: flutter

I want to make a widget (showing tags in a row) that could, and realistically would, be too long for the width of the screen and that you could swipe left or right to see the whole content, I can't seem to find a base widget to rely one. What would be an appropriate way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can achieve what you need with a horizontal list view. You can also check [cookbook for a live demo](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Horizontal List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
          height: 200.0,
          child: ListView(
            // This next line does the trick.
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text('Lorem'),
              Container(
                width: 8,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              const Text('ipsum dolor sit amet,'),
              Container(
                width: 8,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              const Text('consectetur adipiscing elit.'),
              Container(
                width: 8,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              const Text(
                  'Duis porta efficitur nulla ac bibendum. Vivamus vestibulum mi quis dui sollicitudin ultricies. Sed dignissim dignissim ipsum ac sollicitudin.'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Image to show the behavior]

Comment: Listview has a scrollDirection option, I can’t believe I didn’t think of that. Thank you.